# grep specific section or number/word, with R, contained in a text file

Tags: r

I have a text file that contains a lot of different output sections from a research analysis. the text file looks like this...

```
Zone  1         

Dist.   Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone       Zone
Tr.(cm) Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries    Time
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ========== ============
 626.29 000:00:29.90    480 000:00:05.25     52 000:00:24.85     11 000:00:11.75          1 000:01:00.00
 489.99 000:00:23.20    401 000:00:07.30     75 000:00:29.45      5 000:00:11.65          0 000:01:00.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Zone Totals

Dist.   Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone       Zone
Tr.(cm) Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries    Time
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ========== ============
5661.08 000:04:39.30   4360 000:00:55.35    572 000:04:25.35     81 000:02:23.85          1 000:10:00.00
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ==========     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Block Summary
-------------
Dist.      Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone
Trav.(cm)  Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries
========== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ==========
    626.29 000:00:29.90    480 000:00:05.25     52 000:00:24.85     11 000:00:11.75          1
    489.99 000:00:23.20    401 000:00:07.30     75 000:00:29.45      5 000:00:11.65          0
```

How can I grep just the zone total section? More specifically, I would like to grep just the "Dist. Tr." number from the "zone totals" section. But I would be happy with just getting the whole section and then cropping the lines where needed.

I was thinking of something like this...

```
dist_move = apply(data.frame(grep("Totals",dat)+1, grep("Block",dat)-2),1,function(x) (dat[x[1]:x[2]]))
```

But it was just grabbing all of the lines

Comment: Can you please dput the example dataset

Comment: Use a readLines() to import each line as a character element in a single character vector. Then select only the lines of your interest, it could be 5 lines after detecting the line with "Zone Totals" and 4 lines before "Block Summary" . Afterwards use you favorite read.table variant to open the remaining lines.

Comment: We don't know what `dat` and `x` are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file created in the Note at the end, read it in, find the `Zone Totals` line and read the first number in the 5th next line.  No packages are used and it works for both single and multiple Zone Total sections.

```
L <- trimws(readLines("test-file.dat"))
scan(text = sub(" .*", "", L[grep("Zone Totals", L) + 5]), quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 5661.08
```

or this slightly shorter variation:

```
L <- readLines("test-file.dat")
read.table(text = L[grep("Zone Totals", L) + 5])[[1]]
## [1] 5661.08
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Zone  1         

Dist.   Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone       Zone
Tr.(cm) Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries    Time
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ========== ============
 626.29 000:00:29.90    480 000:00:05.25     52 000:00:24.85     11 000:00:11.75          1 000:01:00.00
 489.99 000:00:23.20    401 000:00:07.30     75 000:00:29.45      5 000:00:11.65          0 000:01:00.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Zone Totals

Dist.   Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone       Zone
Tr.(cm) Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries    Time
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ========== ============
5661.08 000:04:39.30   4360 000:00:55.35    572 000:04:25.35     81 000:02:23.85          1 000:10:00.00
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ==========     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Block Summary
-------------
Dist.      Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone
Trav.(cm)  Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries
========== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ==========
    626.29 000:00:29.90    480 000:00:05.25     52 000:00:24.85     11 000:00:11.75          1
    489.99 000:00:23.20    401 000:00:07.30     75 000:00:29.45      5 000:00:11.65
"
cat(Lines, file = "test-file.dat")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. What if I wanted the numbers in the "Time Amb." or "Vert. Cnts." columns?

Comment: Remove the [[1]] at the end of the second line of the variation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again! I just changed the [[1]] to [[2]] or to whatever column I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more generalized method (in case you have multiple rows in Zone Totals) using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

# Split into lines
lines <- unlist(strsplit(myText, "\n"))

# Find bounds of target section
sectStart <- str_which(lines, "Zone Totals")
sectStop <- str_which(lines[seq(sectStart+1, length(lines))],
                      "-----")[1] + sectStart

# subset data rows and extract first entry
dist_move <- str_subset(lines[seq(sectStart, sectStop)], "^[:digit:]") %>% 
  str_extract("^[:digit:]+\\.{0,1}[:digit:]*")
```

### NOTE

```
myText <- 
"Zone  1         

Dist.   Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone       Zone
Tr.(cm) Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries    Time
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ========== ============
 626.29 000:00:29.90    480 000:00:05.25     52 000:00:24.85     11 000:00:11.75          1 000:01:00.00
 489.99 000:00:23.20    401 000:00:07.30     75 000:00:29.45      5 000:00:11.65          0 000:01:00.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Zone Totals

Dist.   Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone       Zone
Tr.(cm) Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries    Time
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ========== ============
5661.08 000:04:39.30   4360 000:00:55.35    572 000:04:25.35     81 000:02:23.85          1 000:10:00.00
======= ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ==========     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Block Summary
-------------
Dist.      Time         Amb.   Time         Ster.  Time         Vert.  Vert.        Zone
Trav.(cm)  Amb.         Cnts.  Ster.        Cnts.  Rest.        Cnts.  Time         Entries
========== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ====== ============ ==========
    626.29 000:00:29.90    480 000:00:05.25     52 000:00:24.85     11 000:00:11.75          1
    489.99 000:00:23.20    401 000:00:07.30     75 000:00:29.45      5 000:00:11.65          0"
```